# How to store map tiles locally using openlayers

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I just picked up a piece of code from the openlayers3 examples see **[HERE](http://purplefront.net/ol-3-demos/find-geo-location/)**, now everytime you click the "geolocate me" button the tiles of the map are reloaded , now is there anyway for the tiles of the map to be stored locally ? I.E. when i click on the "geolocate me!" button the 2nd time around the tiles should be loaded from the users browser locally, rather than being fetched from the internet.

The code for generating the map is as following:

```
var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
        })
    ],
    target: 'map',
    controls: ol.control.defaults({
        attributionOptions: /** @type {olx.control.AttributionOptions} */ ({
            collapsible: false
        })
    }),
    view: view
});
```

I tried the following using localstorage:

```
if(localStorage.layer) {
    localStorage.setItem('layer' , JSON.stringify(new ol.layer.Tile({ source: new ol.source.OSM()})  ));       console.log(localStorage.layer);
}

var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: localStorage.layer ? [JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('layer'))] : [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
        })
    ],
    target: 'map',
    controls: ol.control.defaults({
        attributionOptions: * @type {olx.control.AttributionOptions}  ({
            collapsible: false
        })
    }),
    view: view
});
```

But this does't seem to work, what can i do so that the tiles of the map are stored locally instead of being loaded from over the internet ?

a example i have seen using the DOJO library is **[HERE](http://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/sandbox/sandbox.html?sample=exp_webstorage)**.

Comment: Do you want to store/cache the tiles between page reloads, or during a single page visit?

Comment: when the user visits the page the secound time around , the tiles must be loaded from his device I.E. from locally .